# Python crashes with the code -1073741819 (0xC0000005) when trying to initalize a connection pool using mariaDB connector

Tags: python, mariadb

Here is the code that crashes when executed:

```py
import mariadb

def pool():
    pool = mariadb.ConnectionPool(
        user=config['MariaDBUser'],
        password=config['MariaDBPass'],
        host=config['MariaDBHost'],
        port=config['MariaDBPort'],
        database=config['AccessMariaDBDatabase'],
        pool_name="bans",
        pool_size=20
    )

    # Return Connection Pool
    return pool
```

What I tried:

- Running in a `VENV`
- Running through `CMD`

My setup:

- Windows 10
- IDEA IDE
- python 3.8
- latest version of mariaDB connector
- credentials used are correct as I can connect to db with the same creds
- mariaDB connector/C is installed

Comment: In windows 0xC0000005 is an access violation. I'm guessing that you aren't permitted to create a socket, or perhaps run python at all, but I could be wrong since the issue isn't entirely spelled out.
A bit more of a description, like what is throwing the error (the OS, python, maradb) would be helpful. If this is an OS issue I'd look up Windows debugging for this error code rather than looking to python.
Also, welcome to stackoverflow!
[here's a potential fix](https://kodlogs.com/71961/the-application-was-unable-to-start-correctly-0xc00005-click-ok-to-close-the-application)

Comment: Thanks for the welcome!
I cant really ptovide more information as in CMD it doesnt error out it just crashes the running file while in IDEA i get that error code and nothing else. Something that might help is that i can run the rest of my code fine without that part/ without executing the function but as soon as i execute the function at any part of the code it pops out with that error code

Comment: So instead of dealing with windows i transfered my files over to my ubuntu laptop and it works fine and dandy
so the problem isnt python/code related